# Is there a way to know if a device has disabled soft keyboard?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am mainly working on android devices and some of them have the ability to disable the soft keyboard. I need to know if there is a way via React Native to identify this scenario when the soft keyboard is disabled by the device.

Answer (score 0):

this only worked in the simulator, running it on an actual device the native keyboard still appeared.

wrapping the `<TextInput />` in a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` element in the example below worked.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} >
    <TextInput />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```